# Find all second order partial derivatives for $​r(x,y) = xy/(8x+5y)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am getting hung up on these second order partial derivatives $r_{xx}$ and $r_{yy}$. The answers to the questions aren't what I was expecting and when I modify on a different equation it changes again. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

In this case I would suspect an answer of $r_{xx} (x,y) = -20y^2/(8x+5y)^3$. Issue is I have had other equations that go against that. I am trying determine what steps I am missing to fix the errors in my calculations. It is all skipped in my readings

Comment: Why is $xy/8x$ not simplified to $y/8$? Is there some other function there?

Comment: Is the denominator supposed to be $8x+5y$ or just $8x$

Comment: Start by reading this here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question Then when you edit your post to include your attempt and what solution you were expecting, we can provide help. We are not mind readers, and this site has standards of quality all users are expected to uphold.

Comment: the denominator is 8x+5y

Comment: In this case I would suspect an answer of rxx (x,y) = -20y^2/(8x+5y)^3. Issue is I have had other equations that go against that. I am trying determine what steps I am missing to fix the errors in my calculations. It is all skipped in my readings

Comment: If you just want the answer then type it in Wolfram Alpha...

Comment: I don't just want the answer. I want to know the steps to get the answer as the vital steps are skipped in my readings.

Comment: I just needed quotient rule on the last step. I had a friend assist me on what I was missing. They are actually helpful vs. being admonished on here.

Comment: Can you proceed ? Note that I strived for symmetry. We do not have to repeat the whole stuff for $f_{yy}$ again. BTW welcome on MSE. I do however agree with the previous commenters that showing steps greatly helps  here. Don't take things too personal.

Comment: If you call "asking to give your attempt" and "using correct tags" admonishing, then I don't know what to tell you. Go somewhere if you don't want to follow the standards on this site.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: If you are using quotient rule, you are making your life harder. Implicit differentiation is your friend. For example,

$$(8x+5y)r = xy$$

$$\partial_x[(8x+5y)r] = \partial_x[xy]$$

$$8r + (8x+5y)r_x = y$$

Can you take this process from here and calculate all three second derivatives?

Comment: I am actually try to find xx or second derivative of x in this first example. Quotient rule is the best option. Simplified and already canceling out denominator it would look like this:

-5y^2*2*8 = -80y^2 in the numerator.

final answer being -80y^2/(8x+5y)^3